# How update string field with length of 300 with entity

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, entity-framework, entity

I want to update one field of one table, the problem is when it goes to be bigger than 128 character SQL isn't let me to update.

> The identifier that starts with … is too long. Maximum length is 128

The strange thing is I was adding 300 character with entity , but I can't update it.

Here is my code:

```
var  objcompany = _entities.Companies.FirstOrDefault(o => o.Username == user.Trim()); 
objcompany.T="iii4ca4238a0b923820dcnyeytkekhwertgn56nj67fsjk7eukuyc557654junbi76in67iomoor7m6ri6oi68g4yvmo8709a6f75djyksddu849bSarzindfgdgfdAmita3h65utyjein7gfjy6ybhuh6huhuun676grth6jksc0wjzbc32wbc8w3fiofdj8eufghdjn79yjetyjtey";

 _entities.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: check the size in database table for that column

Comment: @AnkitkumarBhatt It's varchar(400), also I said I can insert new record with entity, but I can't update it

Comment: what is the exact massage like The identifier that starts with ... then what ?

Comment: @AnkitkumarBhatt It's just like what I sent, all OI want is updating a field with entity and length >300

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based On your Code.Update your model before saving to Database

```
_entities.Entry(objcompany).State = EntityState.Modified;//Add this Line 
_entities.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: It's not updating and not showing error , something like nothing happens :|

Answer (score 0):

code first: check model variable and change MaxLength setting
database first: check column in db and change length, then reload model in VS

Comment: I check everything again, but nothing changes :| , it's insert new data , but it isn't let entity to update